# SparkJava: How can I validate an OAuth token in my before() filter?

Tags: java, rest, spark-java

I have a very simple webserver written in Spark-java (Not Apache Spark), and would like to glean off the Auth token from the initial request and send it to a secondary URL for authentication against my company's auth database. I've been over the documentation and am not sure how to accomplish this. I also need to know how to set the query parameter for the request to the auth server. Below is my code:

```
/*
 * This Java source file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 */
package c2c_server;

import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      before((before_req, before_res) -> {
         System.out.println("I'm in before");
         String token = before_req.headers("Authorization");

         // No token, reject
         if (token == null) {
            halt(401, "Unauthorized");
         }
         else if (token != null) {
            System.out.println("Token is : " + token);
            String url = "https://my-auth-url";

         }
      });

      get("/command/:command", (req, res) -> {
         System.out.println("You sent the command: " + req.params(":command") + " and the headers: " + req.headers());
         if (req.params(":command").equals("run")) {
            res.status(200);
            return "You'll run the Java app to push data to S3!";
         }
         else {
            res.status(400);
            return "I don't understand that command";
         }
      });
      System.out.println("Server listening");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doing some research, it looks like the JavaSpark project doesn't have a way to do this by itself. I needed to leverage the Apache HttpClient library to come up with this bit of code to handle a second request to authenticate a token:

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

    private static boolean IsAuthenticated(final String environment, final String token) throws Exception {
          String url = "";
          if (environment.equalsIgnoreCase("DEV")) {
             url = "https://dev-oauth2-internal.com/validate/AppIdClaimsTrust";
          }
          else if (environment.equalsIgnoreCase("QA")) {
             url = "https://qa-oauth2-internal.com/validate/AppIdClaimsTrust";
          }
          else if (environment.equalsIgnoreCase("PROD")) {
             url = "https://oauth2-internal.com/validate/AppIdClaimsTrust";
          }
          else {
             throw new Exception("Environment not supported");
          }
          HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + "?token=" + token);
          try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
             int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
             return (statusCode == 200);
          }
```